# Calculate Hydrogen bonds between each two chains Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

I was trying to write a Python function that will calculate Hydrogen bonds between each two chains in a structure and return the table of atomic coords, atom names and residue number from a pdb file using Biopython module.

The restrictions are:

1. distance between N and O <= 3.5.
2. there are around 47 Hbonds between each two chains in the pdb file, so we take ALA/O from chain A and LEU/N from chain B, the next bond will be between LEU/O chain B and ALA/N from chain A and then we swap again (periodically)

That is the function but it only does one iteration (because of break) and as the result only writes the output from the second string of the condition. How to specify the condition or is there something else I'm not doing right?

```
structure = parser.get_structure('mainc', f)
number_a = []
number_b = []
coord_a = []
coord_b = []
am_a_chain=list(structure.get_chains())
chain_a = am_a_chain[0]
chain_b = am_a_chain[1]
for residue_a in chain_a:
    for residue_b in chain_b:
        for atom_a in residue_a:
            for atom_b in residue_b:
                if (np.linalg.norm(atom_a - atom_b)) <= 3.5 \
                and (residue_a.get_resname() == "ALA" and atom_a.get_name() == "O"  and residue_b.get_resname() == "LEU" and atom_b.get_name() == "N")  \
                or (residue_a.get_resname() == "ALA" and  atom_a.get_name() == "N" and residue_b.get_resname() == "LEU" and atom_b.get_name() == "O"):
                    number_a.append(atom_a)
                    number_b.append(atom_b)
                    coord_a.append(atom_a.serial_number)
                    coord_b.append(atom_b.serial_number)
                else:
                    break
```

I'm not a programmer and need this to finish my thesis. Many thanks for suggestions and help in advance.

Comment: I am not a biologist so I didn't understood much of the description, but seeing your code I suppose the problem is that you want to perform the for loop for every `atom_b` in `residue_b`, so if this is the case you could replace `break` with `pass`

Comment: I'm not a chemist! Does this mean that the ALA/N from chain A must occur after ALA/O, and that LEU/O must occur after LEU/N in chain B; and that that pattern continues?

Comment: I think I should have asked, does this mean that you need to test every atom from chain A with every one from chain B, and every one from B with every one from A? Of course, testing implies taking distances into account as well as bonding.

Comment: thank you for pass hint. yes, the pattern continues ALA/O - LEU/N, ALA/N - LEU/O,.., and yes, I need to test every atom to not miss a bond. I also wanted to set up a restriction on a residue number, but the function residue.get_id() returns a tuple (' ', 21. ' ') so I'm not sure how to extract the number from this tuple..left me with the loop through the whole chain..